# Flink CEP и parallelism

Tags: scala, apache-kafka

Произвожу обработку входящего потока с кафки при помощи flink cep. Описал pattern. Указал параллелизм у StreamExecutionEnviroment. Во flink dashboard вижу цепочку, где сама обработка сообщения с parallelism == 1, а другие со значением 3. 
Указываю непосредственно оператору обработки значение parallelism = 3

```scala
CEP.pattern(stream, pattern)
   .select(...)
   .setParallelism(3)
```

На что получаю ошибку

```
the parallelism of non parallel operator must be 1
```

Происходит это из-за того, что select возвращает объект стрима, который не поддерживает значение больше 1.
Моя задача заключается в том, что мне просто нужно прокинуть сообщения из одной кафки в другую при помощи flink cep. Может быть и не стоит использовать select. Как распараллелить CEP.pattern?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

stream.keyBy решил проблему. Тема закрыта.